# Paypal Node js Integeration Customisation

Tags: node.js, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I've been using node js for my backend and using Paypal as payment gateway. Everythings work fine. Am using the example payment data which is,

```
const create_payment_json = {
        "intent": "authorize",
        "payer": {
            "payment_method": "paypal"
        },
        "redirect_urls": {
            "return_url": "http://localhost:3000/success",
            "cancel_url": "http://localhost:3000/cancel"
        },
        "transactions": [{
            "item_list": {
                "items": [{
                    "name": "Red Sox Hat",
                    "sku": "001",
                    "price": "25.00",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "quantity": 1
                }]
            },
            "amount": {
                "currency": "USD",
                "total": "25.00"
            },
            "description": "Hat for the best team ever"
        }]
    };
```

you see, in the transaction's key there is one key called item_list, I don't want to pass this along in my JSON, Just the amount data is enough.

[image]

[image]

The above images are with item_list, you see the total amount circled in red. But am not getting this amount when I only pass the amount field and not the item_list_field. Is there a way to show this Total amount without passing this `item_list`. It works fine without `item_list` but not showing the total amount to the users, which might confuse the users. Is there any solution or suggestion for this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The issue here would be PayPal are dynamically calculating the total amount with the item_list and not using the amount data.

Comment: how can I resolve this?

Comment: You can try asking the PayPal people to help, because the API is sourced from them.